# Custom formatter in Python can't handle formatted log messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, formatter

I have a custom formatter in my python Flask application, which I've added to the root logger:

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

formatter = CustomLoggingFormatter()
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(handler)
```

This works perfectly fine when I want to log something (logger.info()...), but I have an issue with the logs from libraries, e.g. uwsgi.

Here is an example of a log-message:

> {"@timestamp": "2017-09-25T06:57:45.373Z", "level": "INFO", "message":
>   " * Running on %s://%s:%d/ %s"}

I thought perhaps something was wrong with my formatter, but when I log the LogRecord which my CustomLoggingFormatter receivs, it looks like this for the line above:

> LogRecord: werkzeug, 20, <...>/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/_internal.py, 87, " * Running on %s://%s:%d/ %s"

Here is my CustomLoggingFormatter:

```
class CustomLoggingFormatter(Formatter):
    data = {}

    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomLoggingFormatter, self).__init__()

    def format(self, record):
        print(record)
        input_data = {}
        input_data['@timestamp'] = datetime.utcnow().isoformat()[:-3] + 'Z'
        input_data['level'] = record.levelname
        if record.msg:
            input_data['message'] = record.msg

        input_data.update(self.data)
        return json.dumps(input_data)
```

For my formatter to work, it seems the string formatting must be resolved first, but for several libraries that doesn't happen. Anyone who knows how to fix this issue?

Comment: Please do show your custom code. `Formatter.format()` always has to handle a `LogRecord` instance; the default implementation calls `Formatter.formatMessage()` to handle the actual formatting (which typically uses `vars(record)` as a dictionary).

Comment: Added my CustomLoggingFormatter :)

Comment: Since the formatter implementation changed a bit between Python versions, what version of Python are you running?

Comment: It's using python 3.5 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to always call `record.getMessage()`; it takes the value of `record.msg` and applies formatting to that. The [default implementation of `Formatter.format()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.5.4/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L573) assigns the result to `record.message` for interpolation into the final string. Do you in your code too:

```
def format(self, record):
    print(record)
    record.message = record.getMessage()
    input_data = {}
    input_data['@timestamp'] = datetime.utcnow().isoformat()[:-3] + 'Z'
    input_data['level'] = record.levelname

    if record.message:
        input_data['message'] = record.message

    input_data.update(self.data)
    return json.dumps(input_data)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot :)